# Intermediate value theorem: Show the function has at least one fixed point

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, roots, fixed-point-theorems

Taken from an old exam, I hope I don't translate it unclear.

> Let $f: \left [ 0,1 \right ] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and
>   let $f(\left [ 0,1 \right ]) \subset \left [ 0,1 \right ]$. By using
>   intermediate value theorem, show that $f$ has at least got one fixed
>   point in $\left[0,1\right]$ (aka there is one solution $x \in
> \left[0,1\right]$ of the equation $f(x) = x$).

I'm not sure at all if I did it right but I have taken the function:

$$f(x) = x$$

Then take the given intervals and insert for $x$ the beginning of interval:

$$f(0)=0$$

And the end of the interval:

$$f(1) = 1 >0$$

Because the function is continuous and because the equality sign changes to an inequality sign right after, the intermediate value theorem provides there must be at least one solution $x_{1} = [0,1]$.

---

Did I do it correctly? Did I explain correctly?

Comment: How do you know $f(0) = 0$?  Also, if you knew that then that would be your fixed point.

Comment: Because $f(x)=x$ put $x=0$ then it must equal $0$

Comment: Right, I glossed over that part for some reason.  Ok, but then why are you taking $f(x) = x$?  Every point of that is a fixed point.

Comment: Ok I think I understood the task completely wrong... Maybe someone make answer and explain shortly please? I can create my own function and show it on it? I thought the function was given by $f(x)=x$ in task

Comment: No.  f(x) does *NOT* equal x.  If that were so the question is trivial and *all* points are fixed points.  x is *NOT* a variable in the statement "there  is one solution x∈[0,1] of the equation f(x)=x)".  In that statement $x$ is a value at which $f(x) = x$ but that is not the definition of $f$.  And besides, it is what you need to prove; it's not a given.  If it helps it might be better to read it as "Prove there is one solution $x_0 \in [0,1]$ where $f(x_0) = x_0$.

Comment: Oh ok now I understand it, thank you. I try to solve it now.

Comment: I'm not going to "make answer" but I'll explain the question: $f$ is a continuous function.  for all $x \in [0,1]$ we know $f(x) \in [0,1]$.   That is *ALL* we know about $f$. Prove that there exists a $z \in [0,1]$ so that $f(z) = z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the intermediate value theorem to the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Note that $g(0) \geq 0 \geq g(1)$.